# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths with sqlite (FMDB)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

i'm using the sqlite db with FMDB wrapper to populate my UITableView, i make thread in background that fetch from a server and update the data in the sqlite, every time this happens i reload all UITableView with a notification, and happens that there are 20 reload data consecutively and when this happens it's impossible to scroll the uitableview because it's blocked to relaod consecutively, so my question is if there is a way to reload better the uitableview that lets the user to scroll the uitableview, i'm thinking about Reloadrowsatindexpaths, but if i reload only one cell, i need however to refecth from the sqlite the content because to fetch the content of uitableview i do this:

```
 - (void)loadTableViewInfo
{
[self.source removeAllObjects];

FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

if ([db open]) {
    FMResultSet *sectionQuery = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT name,id,age FROM user"];

    while([sectionQuery next])
    {
      [self.source addObject:[sectionQuery resultDictionary]];
    }
 }
 }
```

the soruce is the data soruce of the array, anyone can tell me how i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably blocking on the main thread, preventing the UITableView from being able to respond to the user's interactions.

A quick fix would be to spawn a background thread to execute the query and place the data in `self.source`:

```
- (void)loadTableViewInfo {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doBackgroundQuery) withObject:nil];
}

- (void)doBackgroundQuery {
    [self.source removeAllObjects];

    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

    if ([db open]) {
        FMResultSet *sectionQuery = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT name,id,age FROM user"];

        while([sectionQuery next])
        {
            [self.source addObject:[sectionQuery resultDictionary]];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The long-term solution would be to use `NSOperationQueue`. Let me know if you have any questions about that.

Comment: i receive this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: i think because in do background query i removeAllObjects from source and when i scroll the table view obviously crash...

Comment: Oh, yeah, you don't want UITableView accessing the same data source that you're mutating. It may be helpful for you to create a separate array (perhaps sourceUpdate) and, inside of the `dispatch_async` block, set `source` to `sourceUpdate` before calling `-reloadData`.